# API Controller added to ASP.NET MVC web application doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that I'm trying to add an API Controller to so that I can make front-end AJAX calls with jQuery.

I have seen several posts on stack overflow about how to add an API controller successfully to an MVC project and although I followed the instructions and have tried to avoid the common issues (I have added the required API dependencies and made sure that my API routes are being initialized before the MVC routes in my global.asax.cs)

My API Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace mywebsite.net.Controllers
{
    public class WebAPIController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

My WebApi.config:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace mywebsite.net
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace mywebsite.net
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();         
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);          
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to send a GET request that I think should return information (in this case something like localhost:12345/api/WebAPI), nothing happens. The browser/http client just gets stuck loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `[HttpGet]` above `public IEnumerable<string> Get()`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the API Controller was being served on a different port. -.-